# Installed Python with 32 bit install, appears as 64 bit

Tags: python

I need to run the 32 bit version of Python. I thought that was what I had running on my machine, as that is the installer I downloaded and when I rerun the installer is refers to the currently installed version of Python as "Python 3.5 32-Bit".

However when I run `platform.architecture()` it states that I am running 64 bit. I know this isn't always reliable so I also ran `sys.maxsize` and it returns `9223372036854775807`, so I am definitely running the 64 bit install.

I need to run the 32 bit version of Python to interface with the 32 bit Java using pywinauto. I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit.

Comment: How are you running python? What operating system?

Comment: I think architecture returns the system architecture, not Python's -- so if you're on a 64-bit machine that's what it will return. I suspect that might be the same for sys.maxsize?

Comment: @suever I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, I'll add this to the question as well.

Comment: What does it say when you just run `python` or `python3` at the cmd prompt?  It will likely say something like: `Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 64-bit | (default, Jan 29 2014, 17:03:59) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: Why not just try to interface with the Java and see if you run into any problems? It could well be that no problems pop up. Don't try to debug before you are sure that there really is a bug.

Comment: @brettb I get: `Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

@JohnColeman I only was made aware of the incompatibility after trying to connect to the Java program, it's definitely a bug. 
`>>> app = application.Application().connect(path = r"C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\jp2launcher.exe")
C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py:945:UserWarning: 32-bit application should be automated using 32-bit Python (you use 64-bit Python) UserWarning)`

Comment: Is there a chance you have multiple installs?  `python` might be pointing to the 64-bit, while 32-bit is installed somewhere else?

Comment: @brettb This is my only Python installation in `Paths` and when I searched for it (figured you might be right since this is a company PC they may have installed it without my knowledge). This is the installation path, `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32`

Now the "32" in the file name.

Comment: Just for $#!%s and giggles, can you find the python executable in that directory, and run it from cmd by explicitly calling the FULL path? Does it still say 64-bit?

Comment: @brettb that actually worked. Now I need to figure out how to call this 32 bit version without having to type the full path. Also, not really surprising but this instance of python seems to be missing all my previously installed modules

Comment: I'd suggest you look into using a virtualenv to manage this -- glad you got it sorted out, though.   Best of luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like you might have multiple instances of Python installed on your machine. Verify that you're calling the correct one by calling it explicitly from its full path, and noting if its still saying 64-bit or 32-bit.

Moving forward, using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) might simplify any confusion of which python installation, and which installed packages, are being used.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine if your Python is truly 64bit by running this code and looking at Task Manager in Windows (or its equivalent in Linux) and seeing what is the maximum allocated memory for the program. If it is 2GB (it could be 3GB for some cases I am not sure) then it is Python 32bit. Otherwise 64bit. On my computer the program executed till 9GB and then almost hanged the computer.

```
a=[]
while(True):
    a.append([1234]*10000000)
```