# My python shell is executing in 32bit although I specifically installed 64bit. What to do?

Tags: python, windows

When I get into the Python shell, I simply get the following:

```
C:\Users\Mert>python
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What confuses me is that it says 32bit even though I installed the 64bit version.

Also, the fact that it says (Intel) on my AMD Ryzen 7 3700X system does nothing but to add more to the confusion.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1425828/after-installing-python-64-bit-on-my-64-bit-machine-but-it-is-still-showing-pyth , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622585/installed-python-with-32-bit-install-appears-as-64-bit, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625099/python-incorrectly-detects-32-bit-system-on-windows-8-1-64-bit